# Backend Product Info Grid Modificaiton

Tags: magento, grid

I want to create a new text field right under the SKU text field in the Product Information > General tab and populate it with the product's attribute set value. What I want can be seen in the picture below.

[image]

Unfortunately, for the past 4 hours I have been trying to locate the file that includes the code which produces the specific layout but so far I had no luck. I 'd be really grateful if anyone could give me a heads up.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable backend path hints to find out which file it is. You can do it this way.

http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/enable-templateblock-hints-in-admin-panel

Please note this is basically hacking. A better way to do it would be to follow something like this
http://www.marketingadept.com/blog/2014/01/magento-developers-add-a-custom-field-to-the-category-admin-page/

It's up to you, speed or do it the right way. Goodluck

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thanks a lot for your valuable info!